# How to find parent vertex of two child vertices with condition in GREMLIN?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have the following graph:

```
          V1
       /  |  \
      p1  p2  p3
```

I want to find parent vertex (V1), if I have p1 and p3 vertices matching the condition in GREMLIN.
I have around 25 child nodes for a single parent.  And I need to find the parent with any of the child vertices matching the condition.

Ex: if P1, P2, P3 vertices has the following properties - name, value.
I need to find parent vertex something like:

```
SELECT 
   V1
WHERE 
       P1.name = 'a' and P1.value = 'b'
   AND P3.name = 'x' and P3.value = 'y'
```

(or)

```
SELECT 
   V1
WHERE 
       P2.name = 'p' and P2.value = 'q'
   AND P3.name = 'x' and P3.value = 'y'
```

Comment: Quick question on this.  Will your edges have direction where they will always be going from a parent to a child? And will the parent vertices be labeled as 'parent' and similarly have child vertices labeled as 'child'?

Comment: Yes.  I do have 'HAS' edge from parent to children.  Parent Vertex has Label of 'Parent' and all Childen vertices has 'Child' label along with properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach this is imperatively (arbitrarily choosing one of the child vertices to start with).

Here's the simplest form of such a query:

```
g.V().has('Child','name','p1').in('HAS').where(out('HAS').has('name','p2'))
```

The result of that query would be `V1`.

Comment: Thank you Taylor for shift response.  Yes, I am currently doing exactly the same way.  But just thinking, if this is costly traversal to move to and forth from every child vertex to parent and back.

Comment: The imperative way is actually very efficient as you are touching the least number of components in the graph as possible.  Would be good though to run this against Neptune's /gremlin/profile API endpoint once you get data loaded in to see exactly what the performance characteristics look like.